# How to test if a category already exists? PrestaShop

Tags: php, xml, web-services, prestashop

I get the category from other database web service and I put them on PrestaShop when I refresh the file to add categories I wanna make sure if the category id exists, if exist I wanna update the category.

```
$XMLRQString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'.
    '<x:Winmax4GetFamiliesRQ xmlns:x="urn:Winmax4GetFamiliesRQ">'.
    '</x:Winmax4GetFamiliesRQ >';

$return = $client->GetFamilies($Params);
$XMLRSString = new SimpleXMLElement($return->GetFamiliesResult);
if ($XMLRSString->Code > 0)
    echo '</br>Error: '.$XMLRSString->Code." ".$XMLRSString->Message;
else{

        foreach ($XMLRSString->Families->Family as $family)
        {   

            $category = new Category();

            $category->id = $family->Code;

            $category->force_id = true;

            $category->is_root_category = false;

            $category->name = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => $family->Designation);

            $category->link_rewrite = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') =>  $family->Code);

            $category->id_parent = Configuration::get('PS_HOME_CATEGORY');

            $category->add();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, If you have large data (and also safe data), it's better to insert your data directly to your database. Use Db class instead of Category class.

Otherwise, you must use a save() method instead of add() method

Comment: that's an option, but for my objective, it doesn't work. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

**This would work:**

```
$default_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
$home = (int)Configuration::get('PS_HOME_CATEGORY');
$category = new Category((int)$family->Code);
$category->is_root_category = false;
$category->name = array($default_lang => $family->Designation);
$category->link_rewrite = array($default_lang => $family->Code);
$category->id_parent = $home;
$category->save();
```

Also, you can always check if an object is valid using the `Validate::isLoadedObject()` static method.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work because if I delete the categories that I have on Prestashop it doesn't add when I execute the file to create categories.

Comment: The `save()` method will either create the category if it does not exist, or update it if it does. Here's what it does `return (int) $this->id > 0 ? $this->update($null_values) : $this->add($auto_date, $null_values);`. I hope this helps.

Comment: It's working now, but is not adding on ps_category so is not displaying on PrestaShop shop but is adding on the other tables