# Verify if a category already exist, if exists save() if doesn't exist add() PrestaShop

Tags: php, xml, prestashop, categories

My project is with Webservices add categories and when I refresh the file of categories it creates the same categories I had before.

```
  foreach ($XMLRSString->Families->Family as $family)
        {   
            $categories = $family->Code;

            $exists = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS('select id_category from ps_category where id_category = "'.$categories['id_category'].'"');

                $category = new Category((int)$categories);

                $category->id=  (int)$categories;

                $category->id_category_default=(int)$family->Code;

                $category->force_id = true;

                $category->is_root_category = false;

                $category->name = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => $family->Designation);

                $category->link_rewrite = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') =>  $family->Code);

                $category->id_parent = Configuration::get('PS_HOME_CATEGORY');

                if($exists){
                    $category->add();
                    echo "created ".$family->Code."<br>";
                }
                else{
                    $category->save();
                    echo "already exists ".$family->Code."<br>";
                }
        }
```

It doesn't appear any error but it doesn't show up on PrestaShop categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `if ($exists)`, as `$category->save();` will already check if the category exists, if so it will update it, otherwise it will create it.

You can refer to your previous question on this topic:
[How to test if a category already exists? PrestaShop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345644/how-to-test-if-a-category-already-exists-prestashop/56346126#56346126)

I think your issue comes from the fact your forgot to set the category as active:

`$category->active = 1;`

Also, you should check the return value of `$category->save();`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I created one category id:25 and when I execute the file it goes to the auto-increment like id:1050. It doesn't add() because I do save() ...

Comment: Simply set `force_id` like this: `$category->force_id = true;`